# Customizing Ubuntu

Tags: customization

Is there any app that I can install on Ubuntu 20.04 that allows me to change the layout of the system? (like moving the upper bar to another place or removing it) Basically I'm looking for a skin

Comment: Default Ubuntu uses the Gnome desktop environment. There are many other desktop environments available in the different [Ubuntu Flavors](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours). Gnome has some customization options, but other desktops might offer even more granular customization. You basically need to research each one, and find the one that fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GNOME (which is the default for 20.04), you can search for many useful "GNOME Shell Extensions". Like you, I do *not* prefer to have a system menu (bar) at the top of the screen. I want my current maximized application to "touch" the top of the screen. For this purpose I use the ["Dash to Panel" extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/). It creates a taskbar similar to the "classic" Windows taskbar:

> This extension moves the dash into the gnome main panel so that the application launchers and system tray are combined into a single panel, similar to that found in KDE Plasma and Windows 7+. A separate dock is no longer needed for easy access to running and favorited applications.

For installation,

- Open Firefox and install the **GNOME Shell integration** add-on of Firefox.
- Go to the link I provided above and select the highest version of **GNOME** and **Dash to Panel** (currently 3.38 and 40 respectively).
- If a download dialog box appears in Firefox cancel it.
- Slide the button at the top right of the page (just at the right of the **Dash to Panel by jderose9** title) to the **ON** position.
- You can configure the extension in `gnome-tweaks` → **Extensions** tab.